# Using CountCols function with Generated columns

Tags: mysql, create-table, alter-table

I'm making an attendance system and want to create a table with generated column which calculates and stores the percentage of a particular student.

I have 2 tables here

1. `subject_name` - division, roll, total (int - total number of presents), 2019/05/27 (timestamp, null if absent), (new columns added every day)
2. division - roll subject_name1, subject_name2, ...... etc

Now I want to store the percentage every student in the division table. 
So normally to do that, the syntax would be

```
( (subject_name.total) / ( (CountCols(Select * from subject_name)) -3 ) )
```

But this doesn't work when I combine it with generated columns.

This is the code I tried : there is error near `select`, that's what mysql tells me

I think the select command doesn't work with generated columns

```
alter table division add COLUMN subject_name float generated always as ((subject_name.total)/((CountCols(Select * from subject_name))-3));
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you for reading through. And a big thanks in advance

Comment: 'Subqueries are not permitted' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html. BUT why would you want to store something which can (and probably) should be calculated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Triggers cannot use NEW.col_name or use OLD.col_name to refer to generated columns.=> does this mean, i cant reference to other tables in the generated colums too?

Comment: You cannot select from another table in a generated column(that would involve a sub query).